# Javascript WebSocket not connecting to Scala server

Tags: scala, sockets, websocket, server, handshake

I am trying to implement a real-time game server in Scala, but I have a problem connecting to it with javascript's WebSocket. I tryed connecting with websocket.org/echo.html using either ws://localhost:8888, ws://127.0.0.1:8888 or ws://[my ip]:8888 .

Here's my server code, whch is pretty much the example from Akka's doc:

```
class MyServer(port: Int) extends Actor with ActorLogging{

  var address: InetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("", port)
  var socketServer: ServerHandle = IOManager(context.system).listen(address)

  override def receive = {

    //Fired when the server is listening
    case Listening(server, add) =>
      log.info(s"The server is now listening on $add.")

    //When a new client connect to the server...
    case NewClient(server) =>
      log.info("A new client just connected !")
      server.accept()

    //When a message is received by the server
    case Read(socket, bytes) =>
      log.info("The server just received some data.")
      log.info(bytes.decodeString("US-ASCII"))

    //When a connection with a client is closed
    case Closed(socket, cause) =>
      log.info(s"A client just disconnected : $cause")
  }
}

object GemsApplication extends App{
  println("Starting Gems application !")

  val port = Option(System.getenv("PORT")).map(_.toInt).getOrElse(8888)

  println(s"Selected port is $port.")

  ActorSystem().actorOf(Props( new MyServer(port) ))
}
```

The odd thing is that I can connect to my server using Python sockets. Since they are may more low-level I'm guessing that I'll have to implement the handshake response to make it work with WebSocket, but shouldn't I see the message from the web socket asking for upgrade ? or even just connecting ?

Thanks for any insight you might have

Robin

Comment: Have you made sure that your javascript code connects to other websocket servers? Because if python connects fine but JS doesn't, the problem may be with your JS code.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right tracks, sort of... Turns out that this page (https://www.websocket.org/echo.html) supposed to be a WebSocket client, doesn't quite works on my browser (for whatever reason). I found this site on a tutorial somewhere so I assumed it was working...